# Is it possible cancel scheduled action from Oozie?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hue, oozie-coordinator

We have a coordinator running a workflow every hour.

Recently, the cluster was KO for a week. The problem is solved and now I see Oozie executing all those jobs it missed during the outage.

¿Can I cancel the scheduled actions somehow? 
Or should I just kill the coordinator and start it again?

Comment: I think you need to kill the coordinator but to prevent this situation to happen again, use `<execution>LAST_ONLY</execution>`  in the Coordinator definition file

Comment: Ah, great, thank you. If you want put it as an answer :-)